# The function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that sets my useState when on click, everything works fine but I am getting a warning everytime:

```
 Line 22:  The 'handleClickOpen' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 20) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'handleClickOpen' definition into its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

this is my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/getBlacklist/").then(data => setBlacklistItems(data.data));

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [handleClickOpen]);

  function handleClickOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }
```

I have tried to replace `handleClickOpen` in `useEffect` with just `setOpen(true)`, but then my page crashes because of too many re-renders.

How to deal with this situation?

Comment: I found this article very helpful for solving this issue https://typeofnan.dev/fix-function-makes-the-dependencies-of-useEffect-hook-change-on-every-render-warning-in-react/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Every render it will create new `handleClickOpen` function. You can memoize it by `useCallback`

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'

const handleClickOpen = useCallback(() => {
  setOpen(true)
}, [])
```

Comment: Why would every render create a new `handleClickOpen` function?

Comment: That's how javascript and thus react works, every renders functions are unique. You can read a bit about it here (step 2): https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/

Comment: try using whyDidYouRender library in you project and you will get these warnings in console.
https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Basically while rendering it checks for previous handleClickOpen & new created handleClickOpen function. Even thought the code content will look same their references will not be right and thus falsify conditon.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvbzSrg0afE&list=PLlasXeu85E9cQ32gLCvAvr9vNaUccPVNP&index=3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLWTnMzWtj4&list=PLlasXeu85E9cQ32gLCvAvr9vNaUccPVNP&index=4

Comment: If you are triggering the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint rule, then `useCallback` does not help to fix it (it just gives the same warning), in which this answer helps instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854902/795690