# A function makes dependencies of useEffect Hook, change on every render. Move it inside useEffect or wrap the definition in its own useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting a warning and although its not affecting the functionality, its a bit irritating to see the error. How can I get around with this. The getData is giving the warning as mentioned in title. I have tried to wrap the definition in its own useCallback, but it didn't work. May be I couldn't understand logic for its implementation. Here is the piece of code:

```
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8081/fetch-all-sales");
      setSalesRows(response?.data.data);
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("freaking error");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    totalSales = 0;
    totalQuantity = 0;
    getData();
  }, [getData]);
```

I dont want the warning to be seen in editor. Thanks

Comment: Is this the only place you call `getData`?

Comment: yes up until now

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492261/the-function-makes-the-dependencies-of-useeffect-hook

Wrapping in `useCallback` is indeed the right way to silence the error, perhaps we can help see why that didn't work for you.

Comment: did you give the dependancy array for useCallback?